# issue when running npm run serve in vue project

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I've got an issue when try running server for vue project

this is the issue

> ERROR  Error: No valid exports main found for
> ' `PROJECT PATH`\node_modules\colorette'
> Error: No valid exports main found for
> '`PROJECT PATH`\node_modules\colorette'
> at resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:622:9)
> at applyExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:499:14)
> at resolveExports (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:548:12)
> at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:22)
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:953:27)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:859:27)
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1028:19)
> at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
> at Object. (C:\Users\AlaaMohammed\PhpstormProjects\vue-2\node_modules\autoprefixer\lib\autoprefixer.js:5:17)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1139:30) npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE npm ERR! errno 1 npm ERR! vue-2@0.1.0 serve:
> `vue-cli-service serve` npm ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR!
> Failed at the vue-2@0.1.0 serve script. npm ERR! This is probably not
> a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I want some to response to my problem

Comment: Did it ever work in the past? Can you [edit] the question to include your package.json file to rule out package conflicts? What versions of node, npm, and vue-cli are you using?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try to reinstall the colerette plugin version 1.2.0 manually

```
npm i colorette@1.2.0
```

Comment: Didn't work for me but upgrading from node v13 to node v14.5 worked.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade Node, you may need to also pin autoprefixer at a lower version: `npm install autoprefixer@9.8.0` coupled with colorette@1.2.0 fixed it for me on Node v13.

Answer (score 9):

Upgrade node to version 14.5 will resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following and it worked:

1)_ First i checked the versions

- npm outdated
- npm update
- npm install
- npx npm-check-updates - u

2)_ Once i was 100% sure the problems didn't come from that source, i typed the following:

**npm install autoprefixer@9.8.0**

and it solved the problem.

Note: try to "npm start" before you connect the scss to the App, just to see if you can visualize something (like: hello world) in the browser, if everything is fine, create the folder scss with the main.scss inside of it, import it and then try the steps.

Answer (score 0):

My node -v: v16.1.0
What worked for me `npm ci`

Answer (score -1):

Updating the node version can solve your problem.

Comment: this was suggested in an earlier answer with more detail (specific node version), why post this?